# Django 1.7 - allow null and blank in the database, but do not allow null or blank in admin form

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a database where I have older entries which contain null/blank values for a specific field. However, from now on, I would like to not allow null/blank values to be added to the database.

Is there a way to do this in Django 1.7, python 3.4.

Comment: just remove the null/blank attributes from your model field then makemigrations? then make some form checks

Comment: How will the database handle to the old entries with Null/Blank in them?

Comment: You can define a default value when you `makemigrations`

Comment: oh sorry, i got the question the opposite way, i understood that you wanted to make them accept null/blank values, for that you will have to populate your database i guess, above comment also works.

Comment: Yeah, I want to keep the existing Null/Blanks. I guess now I know, they are just Nulls. Not blanks.. ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no such thing as `blank` in the database, or `null` in the admin. `null` controls whether the database can contain `NULL` values (not even empty values, just `NULL`). `blank` controls whether the admin and modelforms accept empty values.

It seems to me that what you want is simply `null=True, blank=False`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you! The only issue with this, is that now i can't go back and edit the older entries. I'm guessing if i need to do this, I'll have to do it in the shell.

Comment: Yes, either that, or some check in the form whether the entry existed and was `NULL`. You _can_ dynamically set it, but I don't  know if it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

We did this just by change the `Model` field to not allow null/blank and add default value, and also write a script to add default value to the already existed data whose field is null/blank.

Comment: This isn't needed in 1.7. Running through the migration process should prompt the OP to add a default.

Comment: Yeah, I forget that when we do this, we were using 1.5. ^_^